# Laravel 5 send email throw proxy

Tags: laravel-5

My company's server is protected, so every request want to send outside must throw a proxy server. By that problem, Laravel mail class can't connect to smtp server to send the emails.

Is there anyway to config proxy for mail class such as

```
return [
   'http_proxy' => 'http://127.0.0.1:8080'
];
```

I've been searching days but not found any solution so I posted this question.

Any idea?

Comment: Not clear on the details but I'm sure you can configure postfix to work with the proxy and then configure laravel to use postfix rather than SMTP direclty, in case this is an option.

Comment: I read a lot of people said that this problem need server configuration. Anyway thanks for reply